# Not able to visualize Octomap in RViz

Tags: ros, octomap, occupancy-grid, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am publishing an octomap from a .bt file with octomap_server such that:

```
$ rosrun octomap_server octomap_server_node btFile.bt
```

But when I try to visualize the octomap in RViz, I am only getting this ¿occupancy base? (see image).

[image: image description]

As you see, it is clear that the transform from `/map` to `blocks` is not published. Does this need to be there to be able to visualize it? Also, it is saying that the frame `blocks` does not exist.

In OCTOVIS, I do not have this problem and the whole octomap is loaded successfully (see image below).

[image: image description]

How can I solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287078/not-able-to-visualize-octomap-in-rviz/) by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2018-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it.

Surprisingly, when I added the OccupancyMap by doing Add->By topic, it worked and the octomap appeared instantly. I am not sure if this was a *refreshing*-related problem. If I tried to add it in another way, the octomap was not shown.

---

Originally posted by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) with karma: 101 on 2018-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0